# [Sinonjs]How to verify the function in catch-block is called with specific argument

Tags: unit-testing, sinon

Let say I have a method in a class `UserService` as below

```
async logginUser(event: APIGatewayProxyEventV2) {

    try {
      const input = plainToClass(LoginInput, event.body);
      const error = await AppValidationError(input);
      if (error) return errorReponse(404, error);

      const data = await this.repository.findAccount(input.email);

      // check or validate
      const { password, salt } = data;
      const verified = await validatePassword(input.password, password, salt);

      if (!verified) throw new Error("invalid credential");
    

      const token = await getToken(data);

      return successReponse({ token });
    } catch (error) {
      return errorReponse(500, error);
    }
  }
```

I would like to verify that when the condition below is triggered, the function `errorReponse(500, error)` in the `catch` block will be invoked

```
if (!verified) throw new Error("invalid credential");
```

Here is my test case

```js
beforeEach(() => {
    sandbox = createSandbox();
    userRepo = sandbox.createStubInstance(UserRepository);
    userService = new UserService(userRepo);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    sandbox.restore();
  });

it("'invalid credential' should be thrown", async () => {
    userRepo.findAccount.resolves(userModel);
    const spiedErrorResp = sandbox.spy(respUtilts, "errorReponse");

    sandbox
      .stub(passwordUtils, "validatePassword")
      .withArgs(userModel.password, userModel.password, userModel.salt)
      .resolves(false);

    const errorStub = sandbox.createStubInstance(Error);  //(1)
    errorStub.message = "invalid credential";

    await userService.logginUser(event); 
    sandbox.assert.calledOnce(spiedErrorResp);
    sandbox.assert.calledWith(spiedErrorResp, 500, errorStub); //(2)
  });
```

I am getting failure for the step

```
sandbox.assert.calledWith(spiedErrorResp, 500, errorStub); //(2)
```

because of the provided arguments `errorStub`, in more details:

```
 1) loginUser()
       'invalid credential' should be thrown:
     expected errorReponse to be called with arguments
500
Error: invalid credential
    at UserService.<anonymous> (D:\personal\projects\js_learning\code_with_jay\nodejs_microservices\user-service\app\service\userService.ts:74:28)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (D:\personal\projects\js_learning\code_with_jay\nodejs_microservices\user-service\app\service\userService.ts:14:58) [Error: invalid credential]
  AssertError: expected errorReponse to be called with arguments
  500
  Error: invalid credential
      at UserService.<anonymous> (app\service\userService.ts:74:28)
      at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
      at fulfilled (\nodejs_microservices\user-service\app\service\userService.ts:14:58) [Error: invalid credential]
      at Object.fail (node_modules\sinon\lib\sinon\assert.js:23:27)
      at failAssertion (node_modules\sinon\lib\sinon\assert.js:166:20)
      at Object.assert.<computed> [as calledWith] (node_modules\sinon\lib\sinon\assert.js:195:17)       
      at\nodejs_microservices\user-service\tests\unit-test\user-service.spec.ts:123:20
      at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
      at fulfilled (tests\unit-test\user-service.spec.ts:28:58)
```

I have tried to replace the `errorStub` by : `new Error("invalid credential")` or with fixed string `Error: invalid credential`, wrap all three last lines in the test file into the `try-catch` but not work. Would you give some ideas to work with this test.